# Lubricating a manual hoist

Tags: tools

I was given an old, rusty and very dirty manual hoist similar to the following

[image: Manual Hoist]

which was "stuck" (would only go up). After taking it apart and rigorously cleaning the pieces, the issue is solved.

Now that I have to put it back together, which part(s) in addition to the bearing should I lubricate? In particular, should I use lubricant on the gears? What about the chain? What kind of lubricant should I use?

I am afraid that lubricant is going to keep dirt in the mechanism which I would prefer to avoid if not necessary.

Comment: @SDsolar Thank you. Are you referring me to the tour because you think that this question does not belong here? If so, I am sorry but looked around and could not find a better fit (it was either here or on [engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) which was not really adequate either ...). Where should I have posted it, if not here?

Comment: It was meant as a general welcome message.  You are fine.  I see you have a badge and that is probably it. You're doing great.  I especially like the diagram and good explanation.   This is the kind of question that attracts useful answers.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grease, on gears, not on the chain.